# Faster way to dump data from redis hash to postgresql table

Tags: python, postgresql, redis, sqlalchemy, postgres-fdw

Am doing bulk data processing and for speed's sake am first storing the data in redis before dumping it into a postgresql database in 2 minute intervals. I've used a redis hash to store the data and even the hash keys in redis correspond to the columns in the database tables.

Am using `redis.scan()` to get the list of redis hashes storing the rows of data and then using `redis.hgetall()` to get the data in the hashes. From there I create an SQL Insert statement in SqlAlchemy and perform a bulk data insert into the database.

The issues I face is that I have to first extract the keys containing my data using SCAN:

```
redis_match = 'data:row_keys:*'
row_keys = rdb.scan_iter(match=redis_match, count=limit_no)
```

From there I fetch all data in each hash:

```
for index, row_id in enumerate(row_keys):
    row_data = rdb.hgetall(row_id)
```

The row_data is in the form of `key:value` but its stored in `byte` form so am incurring an extra overhead to decode each key and value manually using:

```
for key, value in row_data.items():
  key = ast.literal_eval(key.decode('unicode_escape'))
  value = ast.literal_eval(value.decode('unicode_escape'))
```

I feel this is too much and there must be a more elegant way to:

1. Get the data from redis using hgetall() and be able to use that data
   immediately for a bulk SQL insert since the keys in the redis hash
   correspond to the column names in the postgresql table
2. Even if 1 is not possible, at least there must be a quicker way to
   get the data from redis using hgetall() and do some on the fly
   decoding of the whole entry i.e. all entries in the hash instead of
   iterating to each key and value

**Edit:**

I've read about postgresql's Foreign Data Wrappers and especially [redis_fdw](https://github.com/pg-redis-fdw/redis_fdw) and am wondering whether its the one to resolve my situation of getting a faster way to move data from Redis to Postgresql with the least trouble possible

Answer (score 1):

The `redis_fdw` is the way to go. Just keep in mind that each member of your hash set will not be a different row in the corresponding Pg foreign table. It will instead create in the foreign table a single row per Redis hash and use a Pg array for all of the hash's values.

E.g. for the following hash in Redis:

```
myhash = {a:1, b:2}
```

you could create the foreign table:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE my_pg_hash (key text, val text[])
SERVER redis_server
OPTIONS (database '0', tabletype 'hash', tablekeyprefix 'myhash');
```

Foreign table `my_pg_hash` will contain a single row for the entire Redis hash set `myhash`. This row will have as key `myhash` and as value a [postgres array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/arrays.html) with all of the key/value pairs of your redis hash.

```
SELECT * FROM my_pg_hash;

 key      |    val    
----------+-----------
 myhash   | {a,1,b,2}
(1 row)
```

You can split the val array into separate rows using Pg's [unnest()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-array.html) function:

```
SELECT key, unnest(val) FROM my_pg_hash;

  key   | unnest 
--------+--------
 myhash | a
 myhash | 1
 myhash | b
 myhash | 2
(4 rows)
```